# How to Update/Save data in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I currently have an application that looks like this, that reads data from an XML file and inserts it into a datagridview on my form [image]

Now when I click on the notes button I have set it up so that it opens a new form, Form2 as pictured below, and takes with it the string that is within the notes column.

The textbox below my datagrid shows the Notes from whatever column has been click on/selected

[image]

Now what I want to do is be able to Enter new notes on form2 and click the OK button to save them to my datagrid, however I'm not quite sure how to do this as every example i've found uses an SQL example like this video here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1pBUGblPKY

Any ideas?

This is how I have it set up so that the XML file fits into the datagrid, I have a feeling I need to re-use parts of this code on Form2 but i'm not sure, thanks!

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    ds1.ReadXml("C:/blah/blah/testdemoxml.xml");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: Aren't you already using SQL?

Comment: Nope I dont think so, I have an XML file which has the data shown in the first screenshot. I'd be able to follow the YT tutorial if I was using an SQL database :(

Comment: Sorry, I get you now. If you want to continue using XML, you would have to write the Xml data when the user Clicks Ok. Do you know how to write Xml Data?

Comment: Nope but I can look it up, thanks for the reply i'll have a look at that now :)

Comment: Ok, will post an answer based on this to help.

Comment: thanks :) i've google searched C# windows form XML datagrid edit/save data and its got some pretty promising results, I think this is what I need to do http://browse.feedreader.com/c/Net_Tutorial/16134011

Comment: Great, I was going to suggest that. I think my answer is not needed anymore then. Happy Coding :)

Comment: thanks :) i'll post my answer when I get one incase anybody else gets stuck on the same thing

Comment: DataSet.WriteXml should work.  ds1.WriteXml("C:/blah/blah/testdemoxml.xml"); or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Check out my tutorial on linq to xml. When the user clicks the ok button on form 2 you will need to update the XML file. Then you wil need to rebind the datagrid using `dataGridName.DataBind();`

You can see my tutorial here for Linq To Xml:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20PK4fOzEZw